# How to calculate the mass of a 3-D sphere collapsed into 2-D plane?

Tags: integration, density-function, projection

My sphere has density, $p(R)=(R+10)^-2$. If I collapse this sphere into a $2D$ plane, let's say it forms a $2D$ ellipse as a result, how will I calculate the mass of this $2D$ ellipse? in what possible ways can we interpret this? Perhaps mass of ellipse=density $x$ area of ellipse, in a rough manner?

any logical answer is welcome, I want to know your thoughts. Please give some basic calculations to aid your thought if possible. thanks.

Comment: If mass is conserved, the ellipse should have the same mass as the sphere. Are you looking for the mass density per unit area of the resulting ellipse?

Comment: yes, that's one aspect I am looking for. What will be the density per area and expression for area? should we do a surface integral of ellipse?

Comment: Well this will depend on your specific deformation map.  Specifically, say that you deform the sphere by some map $\phi$. Now take an arbitrary disc of radius $\varepsilon$ (or some more suited area infinitesimal) inside the resulting ellipse. The mass of this disc will just be the mass of $\phi^{-1}(disc)$. Letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ and assuming $\phi$ is a reasonable looking map, you can get the mass density at any point in the ellipse.

Comment: When you say 2D ellipse do you mean an ellipse with a small (but not zero) thickness, as a 2D object cannot have mass or density. If you mean this, then assuming mass is conserved you can calculate the mass of the sphere which is just going to be $$\iiint \rho\,dV$$